# Calculate difference between rows in long data

Tags: r, dplyr

My database

```
| ID   | Time   | Score |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1    | 1      | 105   |
| 1    | 2      | 155   |
| 1    | 3      | 100   |
| 2    | 1      | 105   |
| 2    | 2      | 150   |
| 2    | 3      | Na    |
```

How do I calculate the difference between last AVAIABLE score (Highest Time) and first score (Lowest Time)?
My code so Far

```
DB = DB %>% 
group_by(ID) %>%
dplyr::mutate (Diff_score = Score[max(Time, na.rm= T) - Score [min(Time, na.rm=T)]) %>%
ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could also use `first` and `last` (with ordering by Time) within the groups:

```r
library(dplyr)

DB |>
group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(diff = last(Score[!is.na(Score)], order_by = Time) - first(Score[!is.na(Score)], order_by = Time)) |>
ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID  Time Score  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   105    -5
2     1     2   155    -5
3     1     3   100    -5
4     2     1   105    45
5     2     2   150    45
6     2     3    NA    45
```

**Update 2/aug (thanks to @ Sari Katish)**: In the case where a group has `NA`'s only, we could add an `ifelse` to the `mutate` and it'll return `NA` for those groups.

```r
mutate(diff = ifelse(all(is.na(Score)), NA_real_, last(Score[!is.na(Score)], order_by = Time) - first(Score[!is.na(Score)], order_by = Time))) |>
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

DB <- read_delim("ID   | Time   | Score
         1    | 1      | 105   
1    | 2      | 155   
1    | 3      | 100  
2    | 1      | 105  
2    | 2      | 150  
2    | 3      | NA   ", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can modify the code to get the index of 'Time' with `which.max` and `which.min` and use it to the subset the 'Score' to find the difference (inorder to remove the NA cases, create an index 'i1' based on the NA values)

```
library(dplyr)
DB %>%
    na_if("Na") %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(i1 = complete.cases(Score),
      Diff_score = Score[i1][which.max(Time[i1])] -
         Score[i1][which.min(Time[i1])], i1 = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID  Time Score Diff_score
  <int> <int> <int>      <int>
1     1     1   105         -5
2     1     2   155         -5
3     1     3   100         -5
4     2     1   105         45
5     2     2   150         45
6     2     3    NA         45
```

---

Or use the `range` after converting 'Time' to NA where the 'Score' values are NA and make use of `na.rm = TRUE` in `range` for subsetting

```
DB %>% 
  na_if("Na") %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Diff_score = diff(Score[range(NA^is.na(Score) *Time, 
        na.rm = TRUE)])) %>% 
  ungroup
```